# DataTorrent/ Apache Apex with sbt

Tags: java, maven, sbt, streaming, apache-apex

Have been working on DataTorrent/ Apex for a while. 
Can SBT can be used to create DataTorrent (Java) Applications?
While performing `sbt clean assembly` in the `root` directory of the DataTorrent Application encountered **Build Success**. But only the **.jar** file was created and no **.apa** file was created.

Following is the build.sbt

```
name := "MyApp"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.9.0.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.apex" % "malhar-library" % "3.4.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.apex" % "malhar-contrib" % "3.4.0" % "provided"
)

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")
```

And the plugin.sbt:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")
```

Is that a bug in DT or am I missing out on something? The same thing works fine with Maven. Came across this when I saw the following post: [SBTWithDT](http://apache-apex-users-list.78494.x6.nabble.com/DataTorrent-with-SBT-apa-file-not-created-td573.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you look into pom.xml generated by apex archetype, you can see following lines:

```
<execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <configuration>
        <target>
            <move file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-apexapp.jar"
                  tofile="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.apa"/>
        </target>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

So, the `.apa` file is basically a renamed `.jar`.